# how can i retrieve date from mysql database and subtract it with current date?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i want to subtract date retrieved from mysql database with the current date and get the output in number of days.please help me out.

i have tried this code.but its not working.i am retrieving date from table and trying to subtract it from the current date which i am not getting.

```
 <?php
  mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  mysql_select_db("lib_db");
   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
  $user1=$_POST['user'];
  $curdate=date("d/m/Y");
 $query=mysql_query("select * from returnbooks where Userid='$user1'");
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
 {
 $getnow=$row[5];
 $change=strtotime($getnow);
 $mydate=date('d/m/Y',$change);
 $diff= abs(strtotime($mydate) - strtotime($curdate));
 echo floor($diff/(60*60*24));
 }
 }
 ?>
 </p>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
 <label for="user"></label>
 <input type="text" name="user" id="user" />

 <p>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
 </p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is not a free coding service, it is a forum where people help each other. Post what you've tried and people will help you. Ask them to do it all for you and you won't have much success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A much better solution than doing your own arithmetic is to use the built-in functions that do this. You can do it right in your MySQL query (`SELECT DATEDIFF(MyDateColumn, CURDATE()) FROM MYTABLE`) or use the PHP function after getting a date from MySQL and constructing a DateTime object from it. (`$dateInterval = date_diff($dateFromSQL, new DateTime()); $daysApart = $dateInterval->days;`)

Answer (score 0):

This will help:

```
$date1 = 2015-02-25;
$date2 = 2015-02-28;
$number_days = (strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1))  / (60 * 60 * 24);
echo $number_days;
```

you can use current date in $date2 variable.

Comment: but i want to retrieve date from the database and not enter it manually.how can i do that?

Comment: write query to get the data from DB table

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to extends DateTime and use that to your advantage. Here's an example of doing so. Extracted from the DateTime class page on PHP.net

```
<?php

class DT extends DateTime
{
    public function getDiff($new = 'NOW')
    {
        if(!($new instanceOf DateTime))
            $new = new DateTime($new);

        return parent::diff($new);
    }

    public function get($format, $new = 'NOW')
    {
        return $this->getDiff($new)->format($format);
    }
}

$dt = new DT('2015-02-26 20:20:20');
$days = $dt->get('%a');

echo $days . ' day' . (($days == 0 || $days > 1) ? 's' : '') . ' ago';
```